# How to get 2 separate div borders to collapse?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to collapse the borders of 2 separate `div`

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="acell">
                <p class="bump">
                    Kingdom
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="acell">
                <p class="bump">
                    Advisors
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My `css` is:

```
#menubar ul, #menubar li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menubar .acell {
    width: 98px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: orange;
}

#menubar .bump{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

The borders are showing on each, but when 2 divs are adjacent to each other, they are displaying as 2px (2x 1px). How can I get this to show as a 1px border between the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tabular displays in order to use `border-collapse`:

```css
#menubar {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#menubar > li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 98px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menubar">
  <li>
    <a>Kingdom</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Advisors</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

give it a border but remove one border (from left or right) add another class for the last child and add the missing border:

```
.container div{
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    border-right:none;
}

.container div:last-child{
    border-right:solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/L63741rg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and set to remove the border of the :first-element when the two boxes are adjacent.